# Using field of association for calculation in scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`Another` has field `some_field`.

`ThisTable` `belongs_to` `Another` and has field `local_field`.

Now I would like to write scope `some_filter` for `ThisTable`:

```
scope :some_filter, ->(var_in) {
  tmp1 = calc_sth(another.some_field, var_in)
  tmp2 = calc_sth_else(another.some_field, var_in)
  where(local_field: tmp1..tmp2)
}
```

I got error `undefined local variable or method 'another' for #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []>`

How to write this?

Answer (score 0):

Scopes are not executed on an instance of the object, they are basically class methods. By using `another` in your scope you don't really indicate for which `ThisTable` you want to get `Another` for. It's as if you called `ThisTable.another` - it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

`scope` is nothing but to define **class methods**. So `self` considered inside scope is always `ThisTable` Class object i.e. ActiveRecord Relation object.

Here you called `another` (association method for `ThisTable` class object) inside scope on self which is class `ThisTable` itself.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. And in my case, how can I resolve it to achieve what I need?

Comment: You will call your scope as `ThisTable.some_filter(var_in)` but inside scope it is calling method `calc_sth` which will need object of `Another` class. So now tell me how that object will be evaluated because inside scope `calc_sth` will be treated as class method and self will be Class `ThisTable` itself

Comment: You can imagine `some_field` as some tag which indicates other information. For example, it can be `teenager`, which indicates age range, or `weekday`, which indicates day range. `calc_sth` and `calc_sth_else` will combine it with other criteria `var_in` to get a dynamic range `tmp1..tmp2` based on `Another`'s data. Then I would like to filter `local_field` on these dynamic ranges.